# Why we study Endo-Trivial Modules?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, modules, modular-representation-theory

I made the exact same question on MSE some days ago and there wasn't any response whatsoever so far, so thought probably I have to ask here to get an answer. So the question goes as follows:

Recently I came across the notion of Endo-Trivial modules (out of brevity's sake e-t), and was a surprise for me that there is a huge (and rather complicated) theory behind them. I recall that an e-t module is a finitely-generated $\mathbb{K}G$-module over a field of positive characteristic $\mathbb{K}$ and say $G$ a $p$-group, such that $M^{*} \otimes M \cong  \mathbb{K} \oplus \textit{(proj)}$, where $(proj)$ states for some projective $\mathbb{K}G$-module. Apparently there should be a kind of modular represenation theoretic argument to study those objects, however isn't clear to me. Do you know what's the initiative behind their study?

Also, there is a decomposition of those modules always, namely 
$$M = M_0 \oplus \textit{(proj)},$$
for some indecomposable submodule $M_0$, and some projective. However this isn't clear either. The latter should be some kind of version of Krull-Schmidt theorem, since $M$ is a f.g module over an *Artinian Ring* (and therefore of finite length), hence a decomposition into indecomposables exists and is unique (up to isomorphism). However the theorem doesn't mention anything about projectivity for the indecomposables, so I can't come up with a better idea unfortunately.

Could you please help me out?

Comment: Roughly speaking, endo-trivial module arise naturally if you consider the stable module category for $\mathbb{K}G$ for a finite group $G$. Endotrivial modules become invertible (under the product induced by tensor product) in the stable module category. As to the last question, the Krull-Scmidt theorem holds for finite dimensional $\mathbb{K}G$-modules. Furthermore, if $U$ is non-projective, then $U \otimes U^{\ast}$ has at least one non-projective indecomposable summand. Hence an endotrivial module can have at most one non-projective indecomposable summand.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @GeoffRobinson! I have two questions to make, firstly could you please be more analytic with the conclusion of your comment, *"...can have at most one non-projective indecomposable summand"*, because it isn't quite clear to me the *at most one* part. And regarding the aim of their study, what you imply is that because are occurring naturally in a certain setup we want to understand through their structure collectively, the representation theory of $G$, right?

Comment: Typos corrected: If $U,V$  are different non-projective indecomposable summands of $M,$ then $(U \otimes U^{\ast}) \oplus (V \otimes V^{\ast})$ is a summand of $M \otimes M^{\ast}$, and has at least two different non-projective indecomposable summands. But if $M$ is endotrivial, then $\mathbb{K}$ should be the unique non-projective indecomposable summand of $M \otimes M^{\ast}.$ As to second question- I gave one reason for interest. The stable module category is part of the representation theory of $\mathbb{K}G.$

Comment: I suppose I should have said that ( at least when $p$ divides $|G|$) an endotrivial module clearly has at least one non-projective indecomposable summand, so has exactly one – Geoff Robinson 15 mins ago

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies, were really helpful. You can merge them up to write an answer if you want. I would like to make one more question, just in case you're aware of. Do you know any reference were there is a proof/explanation, why $T(G)= \mathbb{Z}_2$, where $G$ is a cyclic of order $p$ group, and $T(G)$ the group of  iso. clasees of e-t modules?

Comment: Last question: Because the indecomposable endo-trivial modules are $\mathbb{K}$ and $\Omega {\mathbb K}.$

Answer (score 1):

A good reference for this and related questions is [Endo-Permutation modules over p-groups I](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971125) and its sequel, that contain a lot of the background results. (Here, for example, is where Dade computes T(G) for G a cyclic or abelian p-group.)

A more recent reference, whose references cover a lot of more recent work on the subject, is [Torsion-free endotrivial modules](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002186931300046X), which contains a statement and a reference to a proof of the result about splitting off a unique (up to isomorphism) indecomposable summand that you ask about.